# Read and use data in a table

Tags: python, math, tabular

I want to read the content of an ASCII table, and do some calculations with the elements in different columns of the table. How do I do that?

As an example, the table has 1000 rows, each one with X and Y. What should I do to get X-Y for each possible combination of rows?

In Fortran this is something like:

```
do i=1,1000
do j=1,1000
diff=x(i)-y(j)
enddo
enddo
```

any suggestion for the python way?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight-forward, but this forum is for specific question; this means you should make an attempt to get started on Python, and then if you get stuck on something specific, someone will be glad to help you.

Since it seems you have a background in Fortran, here is a blog for Fortran programmers who are moving to Python:
http://blogs.cae.tntech.edu/mwr/python-for-fortran-programmers/

Additionally, I highly recommend Rosetta Code, which shows examples of how to do various tasks in various langauges:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code